# Why are old package versions missing from apt-cache policy and apt-cache madison?

Tags: apt, package-management

I was looking at the package `intel-microcode`. According to the [changelog](https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/i/intel-microcode/intel-microcode_3.20201110.0ubuntu0.18.04.2/changelog), the most recent versions of this package for Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic) are `3.20201110.0ubuntu0.18.04.2` and `3.20200609.0ubuntu0.18.04.1`. However, the latter is missing when I search using apt-cache:

`apt-cache policy intel-microcode` shows:

```
intel-microcode:
  Installed: 3.20201110.0ubuntu0.18.04.2
  Candidate: 3.20201110.0ubuntu0.18.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 3.20201110.0ubuntu0.18.04.2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

`apt-cache madison intel-microcode` shows:

```
intel-microcode | 3.20201110.0ubuntu0.18.04.2 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
intel-microcode | 3.20201110.0ubuntu0.18.04.2 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
intel-microcode | 3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Why is `intel-microcode` version `3.20200609.0ubuntu0.18.04.1` missing? How do I install it?

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode/+changelog Looks like it got superceded in newer releases and removed on Nov 12, 2020 and replaced by the `3.20201110` version https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/intel-microcode/3.20200609.0ubuntu0.18.04.1/+publishinghistory.  The only version of Ubuntu that is offering that version is 20.04.2.

Comment: @Terrance Does this mean that it is not possible to downgrade?

Comment: Since they removed it off LaunchPad it is not possible to download it anymore.  I have had success in asking the maintainers from LaunchPad as to why something was removed and they got back to me pretty promptly about it.  Sometimes they remove them due to bugs, etc. that are found and can be dangerous.  But that is hard to say.  I can't find any reason explaining why they removed it.

Comment: @Terrance Okay, thank you for the information. The problem is that my computer will not boot without a downgrade...

Comment: @Flux if it's necessary, you can try this build: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security-proposed/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/19438062 (they stage builds there and then promote the built debs to the official repos, so it's the same thing)